# Symbol not found in Lauterbach cmm script

Tags: lauterbach

I have declared clk_proc on top of my script:

```
 LOCAL &clk_proc
```

Later in my script I am using the variable

```
&clk_proc=v.value(clk_proc)
```

I am getting an error:

```
"Symbol not found in this context"
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like your variable `clk_proc` is a non-static local variable and you are trying to access it while your program counter is not inside the declaring function. What is the definition of `clk_proc`? Where is it defined?

Comment: yes Sir, that's correct, clk_proc was not declared in my test program and I was trying to access it. Making it global helped to solve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error here because clk_proc is not defined only **&**clk_proc is defined as lauterbach will treat clk_proc as a new variable which is not defined any where so throwing error.

&clk_proc=v.value(clk_proc)

We need to use the "&" always while **using the variable** in lauterbach.
Try with below:
&clk_proc=v.value(**&**clk_proc)
this will work.